# non static variable cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

I am a Java newbie, so please bear with me and help.

I aim to first play then record sound.

I use netbeans IDE 6.8. Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Reg1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    AudioFormat audioFormat;
    TargetDataLine targetDataLine;
        public Reg1() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("Stop");
        jButton1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jButton1MouseReleased(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(211, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(237, 237, 237))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(287, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(65, 65, 65))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton1MouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

        targetDataLine.stop();
        targetDataLine.close();

    }

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Reg1();
            }
            private void Reg1(){

                KeyListener s;

                try {
            AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("name.wav"));
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audio);
            clip.start();
        }

        catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException uae) {
            System.out.println(uae);
        }
        catch(IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe);
        }
        catch(LineUnavailableException lua) {
            System.out.println(lua);
        }
               captureAudio();

            }
        });
    }
  private void captureAudio(){
    try{

      audioFormat = getAudioFormat();
      DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class,audioFormat);
      targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine)
               AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);


      new CaptureThread().start();
    }catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }


  public static AudioFormat getAudioFormat(){

    float sampleRate = 8000.0F;    
    int sampleSizeInBits = 16;    
    int channels = 1;    
    boolean signed = true;    
    boolean bigEndian = false;   
    return new AudioFormat(sampleRate,
                           sampleSizeInBits,
                           channels,
                           signed,
                           bigEndian);
  }

class CaptureThread extends Thread{

  public void run(){
    AudioFileFormat.Type fileType = null;
    File audioFile = null;
    fileType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;
    audioFile = new File("name.wav");
    try{
      targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
      targetDataLine.start();
      AudioSystem.write(
            new AudioInputStream(targetDataLine),
            fileType,
            audioFile);
    }catch (Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}


    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration

}
```

Please give specific directions, as I am a noob in Java programming.

Comment: At which line the compiler is complaining?

Comment: That's a lot of code - could you be more specific about which line is causing the error?  This comes up quite often judging by the related links, have you read through any of those?

Comment: It's quite obviously the call to `captureAudio()` in the `main()` method, among other potential problems

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the reason behind "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static)

Answer (score 3):

While there may be more formal resources to explain this (e.g. the Java Language Specification), I frequently find myself checking this webpage for these kinds of questions:

http://mindprod.com/jgloss/jgloss.html

It explains these things quite well, also for noobs ;-)
In your case:

- http://mindprod.com/jgloss/static.html also linking to:
- http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: @Karan, please "accept" the most suited answer, by clicking on the "accept" button

Answer (score 3):

I used the "Java Editor" and I tried to compiled your class. I got the error masseage

> Reg1.java:93:16: non-static method captureAudio() cannot be referenced from a static context

The reason is: you call in the method **static** void main() a method, which need an instance of a object. If a method is not declared as **static** you need follwoing syntax 'referenceObject.captureAudio()'

Answer (score 2):

Static means that there is no object (instance of class, like `new YourClass()`). If you have a static function, it is supposed to be "standalone", so it cannot use non-static things, because they use stuff in a real object (like member variables etc.)

Any `static` function can only call and use other `static` functions. So look for the trouble in that environment.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your main with :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Reg1 r = new Reg1();
            try {
                AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("name.wav"));
                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(audio);
                clip.start();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            r.captureAudio();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `captureAudio()` is not declared static thus it is an instance method and it cannot be called without an object in `main()` which is static.

Sine I see you have createed in the run methid new instance of Reg1 thus it is fine then to call the method `captureAudio()` for this object. Plus there is no need for the inner `private void Reg1()` method which BTW you were never calling. I propose that you change main to something like this.

```
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Reg1 reg1 = new Reg1();
                KeyListener s;    
                try
                {
                    AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("name.wav"));
                    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    clip.open(audio);
                    clip.start();
                }catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException uae)
                {
                    System.out.println(uae);
                }catch(IOException ioe)
                {
                    System.out.println(ioe);
                }catch(LineUnavailableException lua)
                {
                    System.out.println(lua);
                }
                reg1.captureAudio();
            }
        });
    }
```