# non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context, testing sort method

Tags: java, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the reason behind "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-c)

```
public class Sorting
{
 public int[] Sort(int[] input)
 {
 //sorting algorithm
    return answer
 }

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Sort(array to be sorted)));
 }
}
```

I get the non static method cannot be referenced from a static context, I forget how to overcome this as it's been a while since I have used java.

I need to create the sorting method and test it in the same file.

Answer (score 3):

Option 1:  Make the Sort function static

`public static int[] Sort(int[] input)`

Option 2:  Create an instance of the class

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 Sorting s  = new Sorting();
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.Sort(array to be sorted)));
 }
```

Comment: +1: However, if the `Sort` method needs no access to member variables, it makes more sense to simply make it `static`.

Comment: because the sorting algorithm is recursive, 
it will call itself

Comment: I dont understand why have u made an object of a class that only has a static method.. shouldnt the class itself be static and you call the function as Sorting.Sort(array)

Answer (score 2):

Make `Sort` a static method!

```
public static int[] Sort(int[] input)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.toString(new Sorting().sort(array to be sorted))
```