# A "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" error appears, unsure

Tags: java, static

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the reason behind “non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static)

```
public void Sort(){
*some code*
}
public void displayResults()
  {*more code*
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
Sort();
displayResults();
}
```

Why am I getting this error? I have sort(); in another abstract class and then this class here is extending it.

-Confused

Comment: Good work trying to make a minimal example, but you forgot the containing class :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate the class that contains `Sort()`, `displayResults()` and main before you can call `Sort()` or `displayResults()` from `main()`.

```
class Example {
    public void Sort(){
        // *some code*
    }
    public void displayResults()
    {
        // *more code*
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Example ex = new Example()
        ex.Sort();
        ex.displayResults();
    }
}
```

Comment: Danke! That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of a class to call a non-static method. Calling from a static method, you don't have an instance, as statics are associated to a class, not to an instance. Therefore, you are not allowed to call non-static methods or access non-static variables from inside a static context.