# Non-static variable/method cannot be refrenced from static context! What is the prob?

Tags: java, object, methods, constructor, static

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Assignment1{
         //instance variables
         double a;
     double b;
     double c;
    // method
    public double hypot(double x, double y){
        x = x*x;
        y = y*y;
        double z = x+y;
        z = Math.sqrt(z);
        return z;

    }
    // constructor
    public Assignment1(double a , double b, double c){
            this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){ // execution starts from here
            Assignment1 obj = new Assignment1(a,b,c);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the values to compute the pythagoras    theorem");

        obj.a = in.nextDouble();
        obj.b = in.nextDouble();
        obj.c = hypot(a,b);
        System.out.println("The hypot is"+ c);


    }


}
```

What is the problem with this code... I m creating the objects... then it should worl fine !! Aint it???

Comment: [Answer is in your title.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static?rq=1)

Comment: Looks like a programming assignment to me... maybe you are trying to use a non-static field in a static method?

Comment: Use an [IDE](https://www.eclipse.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `main` method (which is `static`) you are trying to access `a` `b` and `c` fields which are non-static without any reference to `Assignment1` instance.

You need to understand that non-static members of class belongs to instance of class and they can be access only via such instance.

In non-static methods like

```
void someMethod(){
    field = 42;
}
```

you can use `field` without reference to instance only because compiler will add `this.` to variable for you which will represent current instance. In static methods there is no `this` because static methods/fields belong to entire class, not to instances.

To solve your problem consider either first creating "unset" instance of Assignment1 class (lets say you set its values to `0`) like

```
Assignment1 obj = new Assignment1(0, 0, 0);
```

then you can set its field to data from user like

```
obj.a = in.nextDouble();
obj.b = in.nextDouble();
```

and lastly you can calculate `c` value using

```
obj.c = obj.hypot(obj.a, obj.b);
```

BTW direct manipulation of object field is consider bad design. Instead you should create getters and setters (methods like `getA()` `setA(int newA)`) which will return or manipulate their values.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a new class for `Assignment`. Having the `main` method here is a bit confusing. That said, the problem is that the first line of your `main` method:

```
Assignment1 obj = new Assignment1(a,b,c);
```

Accesses variables `a`, `b`, and `c`, which are non-static variables. This means they do not exist in the context of the `static main` function.

An alternative way to write this would be:

```
// Place this in a file called Assignment.java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Assignment {

  double a;
  double b;
  double c;

  public double hypot(double x, double y) {
    x = x*x;
    y = y*y;
    double z = x+y;
    z = Math.sqrt(z);
    return z;
  }

  public Assignment(double a , double b, double c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
  }

} // end class Assignment

// Place this in a file called Main.java
public class Main {
  public static void main(String [] args){ // execution starts from here

    // Give some values to a, b, and c!
    double a = 1;
    double b = 1;
    double c = 1;

    Assignment obj = new Assignment(a,b,c);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the values to compute the pythagoras    theorem");

    obj.a = in.nextDouble();
    obj.b = in.nextDouble();
    obj.c = hypot(a,b);
    System.out.println("The hypot is"+ c);
  } // end method main
} // end class Main
```

As a general rule of thumb, try leave your main class empty of everything except the `main` method. It's even clearer if you call the class that contains the `main` method `public class Main`. Hope this helps!

Comment: According to OOPS principles what's wrong?
How to code it alternatively?

Comment: I added an alternative way to write your code!

Answer (score 1):

`a`, `b` and `c` are **instance** members. You `main` method is a **class** member.

You're trying to mix the two, which won't work.

Also, since you don't really need a custom constructor for your `Assignment1` class, you can **delete** it.

Instead, try something like this:

```
public static void main(String [] args){ // execution starts from here
        Assignment1 obj = new Assignment1();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the values to compute the pythagoras    theorem");

        obj.a = in.nextDouble();
        obj.b = in.nextDouble();
        obj.c = hypot(a,b);
        System.out.println("The hypot is"+ c);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course its wrong,
you create a instance of Assignment1 with these Codes first:
Assignment1 obj = new Assignment1(a,b,c);

where are a and b and c??

maybe you should use null first:
Assignment1 obj = new Assignment1(null,null,null);

then use the Scanner.in to initialize a ,b and c

Comment: i kept a, b, c as static and now its working fine... :)