# explain a solution to : non static method isPrime(int) cannot be referenced from a static contex

Tags: java

My program is:

```
import java.io.*;
public class PrimeGenerator
{

 public int isPrime(int x)
 {
    int flag=1;
    for(int i=2;i<x;i++)
        {
            if(x%i==0)
            flag=0;
        }
    return flag;
}

public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{
    DataInputStream in =new DataInputStream(System.in);
    int t,p1,p2;
    t=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    for(int i=1;i<=t;i++)
    {
        p1=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        p2=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        for(int j=p1;j<=p2;j++)
        {
            if(isPrime(j)==1)
            {
                System.out.println(j);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Make isPrime static, as the error message suggests

Comment: Don't shout at us, dude. :)

Comment: google `cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the reason behind "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static)

Answer (score 2):

`main` is a static method while `isPrime` is declared as an instance method so you cannot *simply* call it from a static context as the error message suggests.

Since `isPrime` is context-free, you can simply declare it as `static`:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int x)
```

Also, `isPrime` should return a `boolean`, not an `int`

Comment: As an other side note, isPrime should use a loop that goes from 2 to sqrt(x).