# New to Java programming. Trying to reference non-static variables from static content

Tags: java, static, non-static

I'm new to java programming and Stackoverflow and I had a question. I'm trying to display text assigned to variables and when I try to run the program is says that non-static variables can't be referenced from static content. Here's my code:

```
public class VariableTesting {

    String firstName = "Tom"; //String first, last, 
    char middleInitial = 'B';
    String lastName = firstName;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        variable();
    }   

    public static void variable(){
        System.out.println(lastName + "," + firstName + "," + middleInitial);
    } 
}
```

I appreciate any and all help. Thanks

Comment: Search for error messages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static?lq=1

Comment: That's because non-static variables can't be referenced from a static context.

Comment: An "instance" variable is associated with an "instance" of the class.  Ie, if you do `VariableTesting me = new VariableTesting();`, then `me` is a reference to an instance of the class.  Then you can do, eg, `System.out.println(me.lastName);`.

Answer (score 2):

`firstName`, `middleInitial` and `lastName` are instance variables. Therefore you can't access them from a static method, unless it is done via a reference to an instance of the `VariableTesting` class.

Comment: Well, technically you CAN reference them from a static method, but you need to have an instance variable to qualify them.

Comment: @HotLicks That's true

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't have two object that are differently oriented together (static and non static) you have to either make the variable static or make the method non-static.