# Referencing non-static variable from a static context

Tags: java, static, non-static

I was reading Kathy and Bert SCJP 1.6 and encountered the following code :

```
class Bar {
int barNum = 28;
}

class Foo {
  Bar myBar = new Bar();
  void changeIt(Bar myBar) {
    myBar.barNum = 99;
    System.out.println("myBar.barNum in changeIt is " + myBar.barNum);
    myBar = new Bar();
    myBar.barNum = 420;
    System.out.println("myBar.barNum in changeIt is now " + myBar.barNum);
 }
  public static void main (String [] args) {
    Foo f = new Foo();
    System.out.println("f.myBar.barNum is " + f.myBar.barNum);
    f.changeIt(f.myBar);
    System.out.println("f.myBar.barNum after changeIt is "
    + f.myBar.barNum);
 }
}
```

While it was under the topic of shadowing variables, I cannot understand how the non-static variable myBar can be referenced inside the main() method (static)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the reason behind "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static` variable in Java belongs to the `Class` and its value **remains same for all instances** of that class. 
`static` variable is **initialized when class is loaded into JVM**.

On the other hand **instance variable has different value for each instances**. They get created when instance of an object is created either by using `new` operator or using reflection like `Class.newInstance()`. So in your case:

```
/* this is valid since compiler knows myBar
belongs to an instance of Foo called f */
Foo f = new Foo();
f.changeIt(f.myBar);  

/* This is invalid because compiler doesn't know which
myBar this is since it isn't connected to a class */
Foo f = new Foo();
f.changeIt(myBar);
```

So if you try to access a non static variable without any instance compiler will give you an error because those variables are not yet created and thus don't exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting it into simple words. I was having a lot of trouble trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

The trick is that the context of the `myBar` access isn't static.

By writing `f.myBar` instead of just simply `myBar`, you access it in the context of the instance stored in `f` (a local variable).

This is the basis of an often used pattern to launch applications.

```
public class Main {
   private final Foo param1;
   private final Bar param2;       


   private Main( Foo initParam1, Bar initParam2 ) {
      //initialise the fields 
   }

   private void run() {
      // execute the application
   }

   public static void main( String [] args ) {
      // parse the command line arguments
      Foo parsedParam1 = ...
      Bar parsedParam2 = ...
      Main main = new Main( parsedParam1, parsedParam2 );
      main.run();
   }
}
```