# Java - Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android, database, static

What I am trying to do should be simple:
I am trying to use Android Studio to read an XML file and write the data to a database.

A simplified version of my code goes like this:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        try {
            XMLReader r = new XMLReader();
            r.Reader(getXML());
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Creates each station
    public void newStation(int stationID, String stationName)
    {
        DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(this, null, null, 1);

        Station station = new Station(stationID, stationName);

        dbHandler.addStation(station);
    }

    private String getXML()
    {
        //code to get xml
        return xml;
    }
}
```

XMLReader.java:

```
public class XMLReader {
    public void Reader (String xmlFile) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
    {
        String[] stationData = new String[]{"",""};
        //code to cut xml file up and put it into stationData
        MainActivity.newStation(Integer.parseInt(stationData[0]), stationData[1]);
    }
}
```

*(If you want I can add code for station.java and DBHandler.java too)*

Now the issue I am having is this: "Non-static method 'newStation(int, java.lang.String)' cannot be referenced from a static context"

and the suggestion tells me to make newStation static, however if I do so then I get this issue: "'...MainActivity.this' cannot be referenced from a static context"

with the suggestion telling me to make newStation not static...

As far as I can tell newStation needs to be static in order for me to pass variables to it, however I cannot use the context 'this' in a class that is static. I tried creating a context but it felt like trying to dig myself out of a hole.

**How can I get around this programming paradox?** I usually am able to find an answer for any issue here but this is the first time I could not. If you know of a link with the solution I've missed please post it below. Many thanks.

Comment: Where you have defined `XMLReader ` class in the same Activity class???

Comment: And You cannot call a method of Activity class like YourActivity.YouActivityMethod()

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the reason behind "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have an object of type `MainActivity`. This one is calling the method to read the XML.

By the way, please stick to [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) and start method names with lowercase letters. Additionally, methods always *do something*, so they should be *verbs*:

```
public class XMLReader {
    public void read (String xmlFile) ...
}
```

The easiest way to get around is to return the parsed data and call the `newStation` method from inside `MainActivity`:

```
public class XMLReader {
    public String[] read (String xmlFile) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        String[] stationData = new String[]{"",""};
        //code to cut xml file up and put it into stationData
        return stationData;
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            XMLReader r = new XMLReader();
            String[] stationData = r.read(getXML());
            newStation(Integer.parseInt(stationData[0]), stationData[1]);
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void newStation(int stationID, String stationName) { ... }
    private String getXML() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Seelenvirtuose, I would upvote if I had the reputation. I fixed my method names as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You are using

```
MainActivity.newStation(...)
```

you can only do that if the `newStation(...)` method is defined as `static`, eg:

```
public static void newStation()
```

you can access it in a non-static way:

```
activity.newStation(...)
```

where `activity` is a reference to an `MainActivity` object. You can pass a reference to the `MainActivity` as a parameter to the `XMLReader` constructor, eg:

```
public class XMLReader {
     MainActivity activity;
     public XMLReader(MainAcrivity activity){
         this.activity = activity;
     }

     ...
}
```

and in the `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    try {
        XMLReader r = new XMLReader(this);
        r.Reader(getXML());
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Making the method static is not possible. The `newStation` method uses the current `MainActivity` instance (`this`) as an argument to another call. The other suggestion will work, but from where does he get the instance?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I never suggested he should make the method `static` I was just explaining the error and he can pass a reference to the activity as a parameter to the constructor, that is his decision.

Comment: Ok, if that was not your intention, then it is not clear from your answer. You should modify it to make it much more clearer. As for the second part: OP is obviously new to programming. Leaving him _a choice_ that he can't see and explicitely is asking for doesn't fit for a good answer. Please update, and I'll remove my downvote.