# I'm trying to create a Nim straw game

Tags: java

I generate a random start number of straws. The computer goes first and picks 1,2 or 3 straws then the player goes. The person to pick up the last straw loses. I think I almost have the code right but I am getting an error that non-static c cannot be referenced from static context. And I'm not sure what that means. Also, to start the game I am supposed to generate a number between 10 and 20 inclusive. Did I do that correctly? The cup class was given to me.

```
    import java.util.Random;
        import java.util.Scanner;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.lang.Math;
        class MyNim
        {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
           int humanScore=0;
           int computerScore=0;
           Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
           int n, a;
           String x;
           x="null";
           int straws;
           Random r=new Random();  
           do
           {
              straws=r.nextInt(11)+10;
              System.out.println("Straws = " +straws);
              while(straws>=0)
              {
                 a=Cup.c.select();
                 straws=straws-a;
                 System.out.println("computer chose "+a+" straws.");
                 if(straws<=1)
                 {
                    System.out.println("Human Wins!!!");
                    humanScore++;
                 }

                 System.out.println("Straws left = " +straws);
                 System.out.println("Your turn. Pick 1,2,or 3 straws.");
                 n=kb.nextInt();

                 straws=straws-n;
                 System.out.println("Straws left = " +straws);
                 if(straws<=1)
                 {
                    System.out.println("Human Loses!!!");
                    computerScore++;
                 }
              }
              System.out.println("Scores: Human = "+humanScore+" Computer =      "+computerScore);
              System.out.println("Game Over! Want to play again? Hit enter to start new game or type in quit to exit game.");
              x=kb.nextLine();  

          }while(!x.equals("quit"));
          System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
          System.exit(1);
          }
        }
        class Cup
        {
           ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>();

           public Cup()
           {
              c.add(1);
              c.add(2);
              c.add(3);
           }
           public int count()
           {
              return c.size();
           }
           public int select()
           {
              int index = (int)(c.size()*Math.random());
              return c.get(index);
           }
           public void remove(Integer move)
           {
              c.remove(move);
           }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`c` is a non-static variable that belongs to the `Cup` class.

> Non-static variables can't be referenced from a static context.

This means that you can't reference this variable in a static method, which `main` happens to be.

---

See these answers for more information:

[What is the reason behind "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static)

[Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context)

Comment: so if I wanted to access the select method how would I go about that?

Comment: A solution is to take all the code you now have in ``main``, put it into a new non-static method called for example ``run``, and write this in main: ``new MyNim().run();`` Because ``run`` is a non-static method, it can access variables like ``c``.

Comment: I still got the same error when I tried using a non-static method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an instance of the Cup class, you have to instantiate it first in the `main`- method, i.e.

```
final Cup cup = new Cup();
```

Then you use the `cup`, e.g.

```
final int selected = cup.select();
```

You should probably not access the member variable c of cup directly. To enforce this, make the List `c` a `private` varibale.

`static` means, that there's only one of the static variable/method per class. "non-static" (a.k.a member) variables/methods exist per instance.
For example the list c is a member variable - it is bound to a specific Cup instance. If you have several Cups like so:

```
Cup cupOne = new Cup();
Cup cupTwo = new Cup();
```

each will have it's own separate List c.

Accessing member variables/methods works only by specifying the instance they are bound to:

```
cupOne.select();
```

If you try to access them through their class, you'll get the error that you saw.

HTH