# How can I select a random JButton from JFrame (Netbeans Interface)?

Tags: java, netbeans, random, jframe, jbutton

I have created a matrix of JButtons in a JFrame using the GUI of NetBeans. I want to select them randomly, but I don't have any idea how to do it. Any idea will help. Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to have them referenced in some kind of `List`. Then, iterate over the list randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the list of JButtons.

```
List<JButton> buttons;
```

Simply pick one random from it with the `Random` instance.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int i = rnd.nextInt(buttons.size());
JButton btn = buttons.get(i);
```

Works on the same logic like arrays.

Comment: Thank you for comment! But how can i introduce the List elements? When i try to introduce an element, it says "non-static variable jToggleButton101 cannot be referenced from a static context" Thanks again. greetings.

Comment: Cannot tell more if I don't see the code. Generally, this is the solution for your error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static