# ANDROID - create function in service to insert data into sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, service

I've looking for my issues but not yet find out.

I've create a service in android, and I want whenever I call the service I can operate `CRUD`

but I dunno how to do that and the tutorial/reffer is so scrimpy.

Here's my code:

> DatabaseHandler.java and Contact.java getting from [here](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

`myService.java`

```
public class myService extends Service {
    public Runnable mRunnable = null;
    public myService() {

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("Service jalan", "beneran dah");
                mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 30 * 1000);
            }
        };
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 30 * 1000);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        startService(new Intent(this, myService.class));

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        /**
         * CRUD Operations
         * */
        // Deleted Contacts
        db.deleteAll();

        // Inserting Contacts
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
        db.addContact(new Contact("Ravi"));
        db.addContact(new Contact("Srinivas"));
        db.addContact(new Contact("Tommy"));
        db.addContact(new Contact("Karthik"));

        // Reading all contacts
        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
        List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
        //db.deleteContact(new Contact(1));


        for (Contact cn : contacts) {
            String log = "Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + cn.getName();
            // Writing Contacts to log
            Log.d("Name: ", log);
        }

    }
}
```

there's a way I can use code `insert ("Ravi"); insert ("Srinivas"); insert ("Tommy");` in my MainActivity?

***EDIT***

I've edit myService.java class like this :

```
public class myService extends Service {
    public Runnable mRunnable = null;
    IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public myService getServerInstance() {
            return myService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("Service jalan", "beneran dah");
                mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 30 * 1000);
            }
        };
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 30 * 1000);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    protected void insert(final String name){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        db.addContact(new Contact(name));

    }
}
```

but I've an error of `insert` in MainActivity.java when I add code below:

> Error : non-static method 'insert(java.lang.string)' cannot be referenced from a static context

```
myService.insert(this, "Coba lagi ah");
myService.insert(this, "Ini yang kedua");
```

already find out the error on [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static) but still cant understand how to fix it

Comment: Y are you using a service?

Comment: @TominB sorry for late response, yes i'm using service, but i want to call the function from service too, it is possible sir?

Comment: Use DBHelper and Database Handeler. helper for insert.. servi e will work similiar to an Activiry.. 

Or Create a Class for these Funcrions...

Answer (score 0):

use your method calling in onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) cause every time you call a service it'll call this method.

```
        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

            insert("flix");

            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }
        protected void insert(final String name){
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
            db.addContact(new Contact(name));

        }
```