# How can I write a test to print result? [java]

Tags: java

How can I write a test to print this result?

```
package leetcode_one_twenty;

import java.util.HashMap; // HashMap package

public class Two_Sum {

    public int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (map.get(numbers[i]) != null) {
                int[] result = {map.get(numbers[i]) + 1, i + 1};
                return result;
            }
            map.put(target - numbers[i], i);
        }

        int[] result = {};
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // How can I write a test to print this result? THX!
    }

}
```

Comment: Either you can use junit, or you can provide some test-data within your main(string...) method. Odd question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `twoSum` method `static`, and call it with values from your `main` method:

```
int[] myArray = {1,2,3};
int target = 5;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(twoSum(myArray, target)));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @user635967 no problem - obviously change the values around to whatever you need to suit your program.

Comment: Sorry, may I ask more question? Why should the twoSum method static? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Mars_Tina yep - if you don't make it static, your compiler will throw an error saying you can't reference a non-static method from a static context; read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static

Comment: Got it ~  I try this several times and finally figure this out. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what are you exactly trying to do. Why not try    `System.out.println()` and `toString()`?