# Stream and Filter operations on a Map

Tags: filter, java-8, java-stream

I have an EdmPortfolio type that has id (int), name (String) and tags which is a  map as its members.

EdmPortfolio say has an id 1, and name as Portfolio1 and Map could have the following values, 
analyst, John
region, US

I have a List,  At the end i want to have a Map which has all the map values combined from all portfolios. Another EdmPortfolio  might have the id as 2, name as Portfolio2 and Map with values analyst, Smith
region , UK

I want to have a combined Map with Values
region 'US','UK'
analyst 'John','Smith'

analyst and region are the keys to the map.
It has both the maps combined. I have the following code but i am a little lost

```
List<Map<Tag,String>> portfolioTagsList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (EdmPortfolio edmPortfolio : edmPortfolioList) {
              Map<Tag,String> portfolioTags =  edmPortfolio.getPortfolioTags().entrySet()
                        .stream()

                        .filter(e -> (e.getValue() != ""|| e.getValue() !=null))
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                Map.Entry::getKey,
                                Map.Entry::getValue
                        ));


                portfolioTagsList.add(portfolioTags);
            }
            Map<Tag,String> finalTags = portfolioTagsList.stream()
                    .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.joining(",",Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

I am getting nonstatic method cannot be referenced from static context. How do i achieve this?

Thanks for your time

Comment: On which line are you getting that error? Is it even a line from the code in your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the reason behind "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do something like:

```
Map<Tag,String> finalTags = edmPortfolioList.stream()
.flatMap(edmPortfolio -> edmPortfolio.getPortfolioTags().entrySet().stream())
.filter(e -> (e.getValue() != "" || e.getValue() !=null)) // this seems weird, but just keeping
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(), 
    Collectors.mapping(ev -> ev.getValue(), 
        Collectors.joining(",")));
```

BTW: Any reason to break that in two streams?

Comment: @Holger As the OP didn't provide the exact error message nor where it happens, I just tried come up with a simplified version, with less inferred types, so the same result could be successfully achieved. BTW, your comment about the joining makes sense, I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: The OP did provide the exact error message, though not where it happens, but for the “*nonstatic method cannot be referenced from static context*”, the location wouldn’t be helpful anyway. I’ve seen it so often and always was baffled by what actual problem caused it. Simplifying this to a single operation is indeed a good thing and you already have my upvote, but to the compiler, it adds even more inference work, making it harder to track this dreaded “*nonstatic method cannot be referenced from static context*” error. I really hope for future compiler improvements in this area…

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, the location is irrelevant for this error. I'm just wondering now if the Eclipse Java Compiler does something different, because I've never seem such failures to be reported under this message.

Comment: Yes, ECJ works differently. I’ve seen misleading error messages with ECJ too, but not with such a preference for a single error. Also, they’re used in a different context, e.g. the IDE’s assistants make a difference, e.g. Eclipse is more eager (than Netbeans) in inserting needed `import` statements, which makes is less likely to encounter a lambda related error that is actually a missing import.

Comment: Thank you. i was trying to understand and simplify thats why i broke it into two streams.. no reason

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, “*nonstatic method cannot be referenced from static context*” is the error that `javac` often ends up when type inference fails, especially in the context of method references or lambda expressions. The actual cause could be a wrong generic type parameter, a forgotten `import` statement, the use of a lambda expression or method reference at an inappropriate place, or even a misplaced or forgotten brace somewhere.

In your case, it’s `Collectors.joining(",",Map.Entry::getValue)` as that collector has no parameter of a function type that could accept a method reference.
You should use `Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.joining(","))` instead.

Besides that, follow [BrunoJCM’s suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47667756/2711488) to use a single stream operation and pay attention to the filter condition. `e.getValue() != "" || e.getValue() !=null` makes no sense as a reference can never be both, a reference to `""` and the `null` reference, hence, this condition is always fulfilled. You most likely wanted to express that the string must not be `null` *and* not an empty string. In this regard, you should not compare strings by reference but use `equals`. For testing for an empty string, there is the alternative to use `isEmpty()` instead of `equals("")`. So the condition should be `e.getValue()!=null && !e.getValue().isEmpty()`. Mind the order, as we can invoke `isEmpty()` only after having verified that it is not `null`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. i modified the condition as well. change to mapping worked