# Can't get variable from GUI into main class

Tags: java, user-interface, getter-setter

I am trying to use a getter to retrieve some variables that the user will input into a GUI, however it gives me an "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" error. I have tried making my getters and setters static and that did not work. I am not sure where to go from there. Here is my code:
Main:

```
public class creditInfoSystem {
    String name = infoGUI.getName();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new infoGUI();       
    }

    public void getData() {     
    }
}
```

Getters+Setters From GUI Class:

```
public void setName(String newName){  
    name = newName;    
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void setCustNum(double newCustNum){  
    custNum = newCustNum;
}

public double getCustNum(){
    return custNum;
}

public void setCreditLimit(double newCreditLimit){  
    creditLimit = newCreditLimit;
}

public double getCreditLimit(){
    return creditLimit;
}

public void setPrevBalance(double newPrevBalance){  
    prevBalance = newPrevBalance;
} 

public double getPrevBalance(){
    return prevBalance;
}

public void setCurrentPurchases(double newCurrentPurchases){  
    currentPurchases = newCurrentPurchases;
}

public double getCurrentPurchases(){
    return currentPurchases;
}

public void setPayments(double newPayments){  
    payments = newPayments; 
}

public double getPayments(){
    return payments;
}

public void setCreditsReturns(double newCreditsReturns){
    creditsReturns = newCreditsReturns;
}

public double getCreditsReturns(){
    return creditsReturns;
}

public void setLateFees(double newLateFees){
    lateFees = newLateFees;
}

public double getLateFees(){
    return lateFees;
}
```

I can provide more parts of the code if needed.

Comment: To read/write data to GUI objects usually exists a method for that purpose implemented in the object's class. Please post the exact row which generates the error you wrote.

Comment: Please indent your first block properly. Also, do you know the difference between static and nonstatic methods in Java?

Comment: Improved code indention for readability

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the reason behind "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, rename your classs `InfoGUI` and `CreditInfoSystem`, starting with an upper case, it is a Java convention.

Then, when you do `InfoGUI.getName()` you are trying to access a class method, which would have to be static. What you want to do is create an instance of InfoGUI and access it's instance method.

Also your `name` variable should be static because you use it in a static method, ie `public static void main`

```
public class CreditInfoSystem {

   private static String name;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Create an instance of your InfoGUI class
      InfoGUI infoGuiInstance = new InfoGUI();
      // Call the getter on the instance you just created
      name = infoGuiInstance.getName();
   }

}
```

And the renamed `InfoGUI` class:

```
class InfoGUI {

  String name;

  public void setName(String newName) {
    name = newName;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `creditInfoSystem` class has no idea which `infoGUI` class you are referring to. Try and make `infoGUI` a parameter of `creditInfoSystem` and retrieve the data from there.

```
public class creditInfoSystem {
    private InfoGUI infoGUI;

   public creditInfoSystem(InfoGUI gui){
    infoGUI = gui;
    name = infoGUI.getName();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    InfoGUI infoGUI = new infoGUI();
    CreditInfoSystem sys = new creditInfoSystem(infoGUI);

  }
}
```

---

> **If** you are building a swing/FX GUI:

One problem I can predict is knowing when the name in the GUI is actually set. You should maybe consider making the GUI the main program where `CreditInfoSystem` is an attribute of the GUI. Then when a button is clicked or some other action, the input from the GUI is taken and passed to the `CreditInfoSystem`.