# error: non-static method drawCheckerboard(int,int,Graphics) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, graphics, applet

first of all, I'm pretty new to java.
I have to make 2 checkerboards but my code doesn't print anything off. 
I have never seen this error before so I dont know what to do next. could someone please help?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

/**
* checkers
* @author /////////
* @version 3.7.2018
*/

public class checkers extends Applet {

  public static void main(String args[]){
  Graphics myG;
  drawCheckerboard(100,100, myG);
  drawCheckerboard(120,500, myG);
}
/**
 * this method makes a checkerboard in the size that you want.
 * @param Graphics thaks the Graphics as a parameter
 */
public void drawCheckerboard(int x, int y, Graphics g) {
  int row;
  int col;

  for ( row = 0; row < 8; row++ ) {

    for ( col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
    x = col * 20;
    y = row * 20;

      if ( (row % 2) == (col % 2) ){
        g.setColor(Color.white);
      }
      else{
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [What is the reason behind “non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static); [Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context)

Comment: so how can I fix this?

Comment: Applets are officially deprecated - it's time to stop using them - besides, `Applet`s don't have a `main` method.  Also, you clearly have a lack of understanding into how painting works in AWT/Swing as you're about to run head long into a `NullPointerException`.  Stop what you're doing and start by reading through [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Comment: Read the duplicate questions - understand the difference between a `static` and non `static` - personally, I'd recommend starting with a good tutorial - [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) might be a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

Applets are officially deprecated - it's time to stop using them - besides, `Applet`s don't have a `main` method.

Clearly have a lack of understanding into how painting works in AWT/Swing as you're about to run head long into a `NullPointerException`.  Stop what you're doing and start by reading through [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

`public static void main` is a `static` context, meaning it can not reference non-static (or instance) fields and methods. Have a look at [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) and [Static methods vs Instance methods in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-methods-vs-instance-methods-java/) for more details.

Remember, `static` is not your friend, use it sparingly and wisely.

Instead of trying to fix your code directly, because `Applet` is dead, I've provided a simple example of how painting should be done...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            drawCheckerboard(100, 100, g2d);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        protected void drawCheckerboard(int x, int y, Graphics2D g) {
            int row;
            int col;

            for (row = 0; row < 8; row++) {

                for (col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                    x = col * 20;
                    y = row * 20;

                    if ((row % 2) == (col % 2)) {
                        g.setColor(Color.white);
                    } else {
                        g.setColor(Color.black);
                        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Now, there are also two issues with your painting routine.  The first, it's not actually using the `x`/`y` parameters passed to it, so both boards are getting painted to the same location.  Second, it's ignoring the `white` cell.

You can fix this simply enough...

```
protected void drawCheckerboard(int x, int y, Graphics2D g) {
    int row;
    int col;

    for (row = 0; row < 8; row++) {

        for (col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
            int xPos = col * 20;
            int yPos = row * 20;

            if ((row % 2) == (col % 2)) {
                g.setColor(Color.white);
            } else {
                g.setColor(Color.black);
            }
            g.fillRect(x + xPos, y + yPos, 20, 20);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you'll need to change the `getPreferredSize` to accomodate the content...

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(280, 660);
}
```