# error: non-static method unbind() cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: android, butterknife

I am changing Bind to BindView Class, How To Write right Way I Dont know, I am new in coding 
Please Help me

```
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.Unbinder;
import static butterknife.Unbinder.*;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
 @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub code part

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_device_info, container, false);
    Unbinder unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    mContext = getActivity();

    return view;
}


@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    Unbinder.unbind();
}
```

Please Help me

Comment: see this link that may help you     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static

Comment: Make `Unbinder unbinder` a field, and use that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Unbinder unbinder; //declare it here 
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
 @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...........
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view); //bind it here

    .......

    return view;
}


@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    unbinder.unbind(); // then unbind it here on the same Unbinder object
}
```