# non-static method 'compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' cannot be reference from a static context

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I tried compressing my image in my android app by using:

```
Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, byteArrayOutputStream);
```

But I am getting the above error. What's the best way for me to do this without experiencing the error?

Comment: *Search* for the error message (["non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"](https://www.google.com/search?q=non-static+method+cannot+be+referenced+from+a+static+context)). *Read* about the cause (and how to use instance methods). *Apply* new knowledge. Finish program. Win.

Comment: did you call this line in static method?

Comment: Did you ever wonder which bit map would be compressed by your code line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the reason behind "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static)

Answer (score 1):

The [`compress()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream)) of `Bitmap` is an "instance method" (as opposed to a "static method"). This means that it must be invoked on an actual existing `Bitmap` object, rather than on the `Bitmap` class itself.

In other words:

```
Bitmap uncompressed = /* some bitmap you've gotten from somewhere */
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
uncompressed.compress(..., out);
Bitmap compressed = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
```

Here were are invoking `compress()` on the `uncompressed` bitmap instance.

On some level, this makes intuitive sense. If you were able to simply write:

```
Bitmap compressed = Bitmap.compress(...);
```

Then you'd have to ask yourself: what are you compressing?

Comment: `Bitmap compressed = uncompressed.compress(...)` - the method `compress` returns a `boolean`, not a `Bitmap`.

Comment: You're right, sorry. The third argument to the `compress()` method is an `OutputStream` that receives the compressed bitmap.