# GroupingBy using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I am working with `Java 8 Streams` I have a class  like below:

```
public class ShareDao {
    private String senderId;
    private String receiverId;

    public String getSenderId() {
        return senderId;
    }

    public String sharingMode(){
        return this.receiverId != null && !this.receiverId.trim().isEmpty() ? "incoming" : "outgoing";
    }
}
```

Now what I am trying to do is, I want to:

1. Filter out the records where senderId is invalid (using a Map<> lookup)
2. Group the collection by the senderId and then further group them by the shareMode.

Below is my code:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<ShareDao>>> p = records.stream()
            .filter(shared -> userMap.containsKey(shared.getSenderId()))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ShareDao::getSenderId), Collectors.groupingBy(ShareDao::sharingMode, Function.identity()));
```

It throws me the error:

> Error:(105, 90) java: no suitable method found for groupingBy(Share[...]gMode,java.util.function.Function)
>       method java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy(java.util.function.Function) is not applicable
>         (cannot infer type-variable(s) T,K
>           (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
>       method java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector) is not applicable
>         (no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that java.util.function.Function conforms to java.util.stream.Collector)
>       method java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.stream.Collector) is not applicable
>         (cannot infer type-variable(s) T,K,D,A,M
>           (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))

While `Intellij Idea` raises the error

`Non-Static method cannot be referenced from static context`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the reason behind "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static)

Comment: Can you please read the question again? How is it a duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you're trying to achieve

> - Filter out the records where senderId is invalid (using a Map<>
>     lookup)
> - Group the collection by the senderId and then further group them by    the shareMode.

you can instead use:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<ShareDao>>> p = records.stream()
        .filter(shared -> userMap.containsKey(shared.getSenderId())) // filter records
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ShareDao::getSenderId, // grouping by senderId
                Collectors.groupingBy(ShareDao::sharingMode)));  //further grouping by sharingMode
```

***Note***:

1. `groupingBy` attributes results in values to be aggregated as a `List`.
2. the `Collector` defined within the `collect` as it differs from your attempt.

Comment: I edited the question, that `List` was just a copy paste error since I changed class names and types to fit the question.

Comment: @iam.Carrot I hope the point (2) still holds for an answer :)

Comment: Yes and hence I've marked it as the answer, thank you.