# Method Calling (Static/Non-Static)

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm kind of new to Java and I'm struggling with calling a method from another class.

Class 1

```
public void SetColourCheck()
    {
        this.Tick = ColourCheck;
    }

    public JLabel GetColourCheck()
    {
        return this.Tick;
    }
```

Class 2

```
public void TickCheck()
    {
        JLabel Tick = GUI.GetColourCheck();

        ColourState();
        Tick.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

On Class 2, I'm getting the error `non-static method GetColourCheck() cannot be referenced from a static context` on JLabel Tick.

Edited:
Is this what you mean when you say Constructor code?

```
public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    GUI TestGUI;
    public JLabel Tick;

    public GUI(GUI aThis) {
        initComponents();
        TestGUI = aThis;
    }
```

All this appears in the console.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Scoring.ColourPicker.ColourState(ColourPicker.java:345)
    at Scoring.ColourPicker.BlueSliderStateChanged(ColourPicker.java:326)
    at Scoring.ColourPicker.access$500(ColourPicker.java:13)
    at Scoring.ColourPicker$6.stateChanged(ColourPicker.java:197)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JSlider.fireStateChanged(JSlider.java:439)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JSlider$ModelListener.stateChanged(JSlider.java:354)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.fireStateChanged(DefaultBoundedRangeModel.java:371)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.setRangeProperties(DefaultBoundedRangeModel.java:309)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.setValueIsAdjusting(DefaultBoundedRangeModel.java:238)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JSlider.setValueIsAdjusting(JSlider.java:652)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSliderUI$TrackListener.mouseDragged(BasicSliderUI.java:2081)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseMotionEvent(Component.java:6680)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseMotionEvent(JComponent.java:3360)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6401)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4564)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the reason behind "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public void SetColourCheck()` is an instance method, which can be called using an object alone. Assuming the class name is `GUI` , the call you did `GUI.GetColourCheck()` is not using the object of GUI.

So it must be like `new GUI().SetColourCheck()` or use the object if you have created one.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense now.

Comment: It works but doesn't, I'm now getting this error in the console, followed by loads more text.
`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: From these lines of code you posted, its hard to say what caused the NPE

Comment: I have only received that error from `new GUI().SetColourCheck()`. If that helps? I would make this a separate question itself but It will not allow me to.

Comment: Post the entire stack trace and constructor code of GUI

Comment: I'll edit the main question