# generic method return type must be also generic?

Tags: java, arraylist, generic-list

I was told to create a method that combine two generic `ArrayList`.
Here is the code, and I've several questions:

```
 public static <T> List<T> combineArrayList(List<T> list_Array1, List<T> list_Array2){
    List<T> returnList = new ArrayList<T>();
    int i;
    for(i = 0;i< list_Array1.size();i++){
        returnList.add(list_Array1.get(i));
    }
    for(i = 0;i< list_Array2.size();i++){
        returnList.add(list_Array2.get(i));
    }
    return returnList;
}

public static  <T> void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a list and add some colors to the list
    List<String> list_Strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list_Strings2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<T> returnedList = new ArrayList<T>();
    list_Strings.add("Red");
    list_Strings2.add("yellow");

    returnedList = (List<T>) combineArrayList(list_Strings,list_Strings2);
    // Print the list
    System.out.println(returnedList);

}
```

1. I dont really understand why the compiler want to add `static` to the function `combineArray()`
2. In the main function prototype, I needed to add the `generic` declaration as `<T>` every time when I want to use Generic type in the function?
3. I've created an Generic variable that will have the return data from the function, by far I know it will be return as `List<String>` how should I declare the variable as `List<T>` or `List<String>`, what is the convention?
4. Why the compiler want me to cast the type of the `combineArrayList()` to `List<T>` which his return type is already `List<T>`?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. You don't have to, but you're invoking it from a static context, so you either need to create an instance of the containing class, or make the method static.

Comment: 2. You don't need the `<T>` on `main`. Using it here doesn't make sense.

Comment: The `returnedList` in `main()` should be type `List<String>`, which is what that particular `combineArrayList()` call returns. It doesn't return a `List<T>` because the `T` has already been resolved by the compiler to `String`.

Comment: @AndyTurner, Thank you for your help, i've understand the answer for 2,3,4 questions.
But about Q.1, the compiler force me to put `static` on the function prototype.
if I remove it i get `Non-static method 'combineArrayList(java.util.List<T>, java.util.List<T>)' cannot be referenced from a static context` can you please explain this? and how can i create an instance for the main class I dont really understand.

Comment: @itzikb https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your are calling the function from static context. So it needs to be static or create object of the class.
2. You are forced to do so because of this line in your code `List<T> returnedList = new ArrayList<T>();` as you are specifying a generic type here. Generics are not evaluated at runtime.
3. You can do something like this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a list and add some colors to the list
    List<String> list_Strings = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list_Strings2 = new ArrayList<>();
    list_Strings.add("Red");
    list_Strings2.add("yellow");
    List<String> returnedList = combineArrayList(list_Strings, list_Strings2);
    // Print the list
    System.out.println(returnedList);

  }
```

4. The compiler does not know what will be returned by your `combineArrayList()` function and you want to assign it to `List<T>`.