# Cant use getter because of non-static method

Tags: java

I have CarService.java class, List of car and getter inside. Like this:

```
public class CarService {
public Scanner scanner;
private List<Car> cars;
private List<Person> persons;
private List<BankAccount> accounts;


public List<Car> getcarlist() {
    return cars;
}
private void initalizeCars() {...}
```

Another Class Car.java. Here I want to use

```
CarService.getcarlist().add(rest...)
```

The error is: Non-static method 'getcarlist()' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the reason behind "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static)

Comment: you need to create instance of CarService and use that referece to be able to call the method. Since, getcarlist() is not a static method, you cannot reference it using CarService .xxx()